# How do you choose when to use DIV and when SPAN, to wrap something?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

How do you choose when to use `DIV` and when `SPAN`, to wrap something?

Many time when we make PSD 2 HTML, in some conditions to get any effect or to wrap something to get needed effect, we use `div` or `span`.

And I know `div` is block level element and `span` is inline level element and we can change display properties through CSS. and I also know `div` cannot come inside `span`.

What are cases when you use `div` as a `display:inline` and `span` as a `display:block`? and should we try to avoid those scenarios? is this semantically incorrect?

and when we use blank `div` or `span` (no content inside) to get some effect, than which is correct?

Comment: If you have a free choice, just pick the most convenient one. In HTML, there isn't always a "one true way".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you note, you should use `div`s as dividers of blocks, and `span`s for marking inline content.

And yes, you should try to avoid changing the display types of them.

Comment: Well said... changing the display types on div/span is almost equivalent of making b tag to be italic and i tag to be bold... and trust me, I have seen folks doing that. :P

Comment: Yes. and sometime inside a any block level element we can use a block level element and inline level element both. and both will do, but which one we should choose?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas - if the internal content is inline, use a `span`, if a block, use a `div`.

Comment: @Oded - my questions is when we use blank `div` or `span` (no content inside) to get some effect, than which is correct.

Comment: @Jitendra: As far as I know, if your span has empty content, it will not get rendered properly unless you force a blank with a nbsp in it.

Comment: It's actually pretty logical. Whenever you're forced to add `display:inline` to the `div`, then it should have been a `span` from the beginning on and vice versa.

Comment: @BalusC - So if we need width and height for blank tag then it should be always `div` , `span` shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding blank element, `div` is better as you can define its width and height while for `span` it won't have proper effect.

Most simple example to prove this point can be seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/4DZkV/

Comment: This is because height/width can only be given to block level elements. As said in the question, by default div is a block element, and span an inline element. So for empty elements, depends a bit what you want to do with them. Span would make sense if the empty element was needed inside normal text-flow, and was for ex. intended to get content by AJAX. Empty div would make sense, if you need a block-level divider, get an image by AJAX etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is still a good question but the suggested answers only seem to address part of the question. There are three CSS display types, which help put this into perspective: `inline`, `block`, and `inline-block`. If you read this other Stackoverflow topic, [CSS display: inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block), I think you'll get some useful guidelines. For example, if you need to ensure the element has distinct top and bottom padding and margins, then it probably needs to be a `div` (with CSS style `inline-block`), otherwise a `span` is probably a better choice.