# center align triangle along with text

Tags: html, css, shapes

I am trying to use triangle (pure css) in my website for upvoting and downvoting. I have created triangles but am not able to align them along with the text where likes and dislikes are written.

[image: This image shows how the triangles are showing up]

I want them aligned with the text with minimal code.

.css

```
.vote{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.upvote{
    border-bottom: 10px solid #7d7d7d;
}
.downvote{
    border-top: 10px solid #7d7d7d;
}

.upvoted{
    border-bottom: 10px solid teal;
}
.downvoted{
    border-top: 10px solid #ab102f;
}
```

.html

```
<span id='votings'><span class='vote upvoted'></span>
<?php echo $current['likes'];?>
<span class='vote downvote'></span>
<?php echo $current['dislikes'];?>
<?php echo $current['action'];?>
</span>
```

Help me doing this with minimal added code. Any help, advice, suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

**I tried negative margin-top too. But didn't help.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to your `.vote` class, because `<span>` is an `inline` element by default.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wE4RJ/1/)

**CSS**

```
.vote{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: great this works..i tried `display:inline;`, i never understood difference between the two. Can you please explain?

Comment: @optim - Have a read through this to explain the differences between `inline` and `inline-block`, I think it has probably been answered many time here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

if I well understood, just add `display: inline-block;` to `.vote`

http://jsbin.com/ehamoj/1/

Comment: great this works..i tried `display:inline;`, i never understood difference between the two. Can you please explain?

Comment: [display inline vs. inline-block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)