# How to contain a div floating outside of container div

Tags: css, html, overflow

I'm making a 'topic' design, and I am having issues again. I have a floating div (to the left) inside a container div and it's going outside of it's boundries. It's dynamic, so setting a height: property will not suffice. Now I know it's the float: left; that's causing it, but how can I try fitting in it? I tried setting outer div to display: table; which works, but then it doesn't set the other div next to the floating one to fill the width.

[image]

html:

```
    <div class="reply-wrapper">
    <div class="reply-box">
        <div class="reply-header">
            <span id="post-id">#1</span>
            <span id="post-date">Today, 12:08</span>
        </div>
        <div class="reply-main">
            <div class="user-info">
                <div class="username-wrap">
                    <span id="username">Jakes625</span>
                    <!-- img online or not? -->
                </div>
                <span id="usertitle">Admin</span>
                <ul class="user-stats">
                    <li>Posts: 99</li>
                    <li>Rep: 99</li>
                    <li>Likes: 99</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="reply-data">
                <div class="reply-post">
                    <h2>Post Title</h2>
                    <p>
                        So this is some text that goes in a post.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="reply-signature">
                    This is an example signature.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reply-footer">
            <span class="reply-button">Reply With Quote</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
    .reply-wrapper{
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
    font: normal 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
.reply-box{
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.reply-box:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.reply-header{
    background-color: #474747;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.reply-header #post-id{
    float: right;
}
.reply-main{
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.reply-main .user-info{
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding: 10px;
}
.reply-main .reply-data{
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.user-info .username-wrap,.user-info #usertitle{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.username-wrap #username{
    font-size: 11pt;
}
.user-stats{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.user-stats li{
    background: #f2f2f2 none;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.reply-post{
    padding: 10px;
}
.reply-post h2{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.reply-signature{
    border-top: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding: 10px;
}
.reply-footer{
    padding: 4px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-top: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}
.reply-footer .reply-button{
    float: right;
}
```

PAGE SOURCE: http://jakes625.toomanylols.com/thread.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
.reply-main .user-info{
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding: 10px;
}
.reply-main .reply-data{
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

to:

```
.reply-main .user-info{
    width: 180px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding: 10px;
}
.reply-main .reply-data{
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will display both divs side by side, while stretching the outer div to make them fit. If what you want is the contrary (make the div's height equal the outer div's height, regardless of it's content) then the other posted answer is what you're looking for

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4bax/)

Comment: They have to be side by side :p, that puts userinfo on top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block (in case you're confusing inline with inline-block) =)

Comment: you need to add `inline-block` to the .reply-data div too ;)

Comment: I'm using your jsfiddle! :P maybe browser issue? I'm using chrome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39578/discussion-between-jakes625-and-nicolas-straub-valdivieso)

Answer (score 0):

Overflow hidden the reply-wrapper part (the outter container)

CSS

```
.reply-wrapper {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  color: #333333;
  font: 12px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.reply-main {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This works, although if the reply-data is bigger it looks weird.

Comment: OK, i gave you a way to do it by setting overflow:hidden to outter container .. If you cannot figure out the rest of it and want a copy-paste solution for your specific needs : PAY ME.

Comment: okay I'll pay. lol. Your way works, but not when the reply-data has a height greater than the height of the user-info. :p

Comment: Do you have some way I could contact you?

Comment: @Jakes625 No need to contact me, Nicolás Straub Valdivieso gave you the fix.