# Something in my CSS is making my making the text element appear a line below its label

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using `simple_form_for` in Rails 3.2.16 along with `Twitter Bootstrap` for my forms. Yet on all of my forms. I'm using the `form-horizontal` class. Yet all of my text elements appear below and to the right of their labels. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="control-group text optional">
  <label class="text optional" for="user_email">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="user_email" class="text optional" type="text" value="adrian.klingel@myfitment.com" size="30" name="user[email]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Barring a screenshot, here is a representation of what the screen looks like:

```
Email:
               <Text box for email>
```

I'm using `Firebug` to try to debug. I haven't customized the CSS. All settings are being inherited from the bootstrap css.

Label is set with:

```
display: block;
```

There are many settings in Bootstrap for `.form-horizontal`.

I can see in the layout view that the `.controls` div is padded out 180px to the right. But I can't understand what is forcing it down. It needs to be in line with its label. As somebody with a programming background, I don't have the words to describe my frustration with CSS. I just can not get it. Not for a lack of trying.

---

UPDATE:

---

I was able to achieve what I wanted by applying `float:left;` to the label, but I'm just kind of surprised that the packaged `form-horizontal` class doesn't have that in there already. I'm not sure what they think `form-horizontal` should mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another useful way to achieve what you said you achieved with `float: left;` is to use `display: inline-block;` instead.

`display: block;` forces a line break.

Read more about it here:
[CSS display: inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)