# CSS/HTML How to Align Text

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

Today I am wondering how to align text horizontally. us.mineplex.com The forums, shop, title, etc are aligned perfectly and horizontal. How do they do that? I tried to figure it out my self and need some help, Thanks.

CSS:

```
.header_container{
width: 100%;
height: 185px;
background-color: black;

}

.navtabscontainer{

    background-color:   #6ED16E;
    border-top-left-radius: 9px;
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 180px;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;



}

.headerlogo{

    background-image: url('logo.png');


}

.divider{

    height: 49;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 109px;
    top: -16px;


}

.navtabs{

color: white;
text-decoration: none; 
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 30px;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center; 


}

* {
margin: 0;


}

.textip{


    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 300px;
    top: 100px;



}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>Minetage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

   <div class="header_container">
    <h3 class="textip">Server IP: Minetage.com</h3>
    <div class="header_logo">
    <div class="navtabscontainer">
            <ul class="navtabs">
                <li href="Games">Games</i>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li href="Games">Forums</i>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li href="Games">Home</i>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li href="Games">Leaderboards</i>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li href="Games">Contact</li>
            </ul>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are the end tag `</div>`s??

Answer (score 2):

You can make your list appear inline like this:

```
.navtabs li {
    display:inline;
}
```

This way you won't need the empty list items as dividers.

If you want to space them out, add left/right padding or margins to the anchor inside (which you'll need anyway if it's a menu).

```
<ul class="navtabs">
    <li><a href="myPage.htm">Games</a></i>
    <li><a href="myOtherPage.htm">Stuff</a></i>
</ul>
```

then

```
ul.navtabs li a   {
    display:block;
    padding: 0 2em;
}
```

Assigning `display:inline;` to the list item, then `display:block;` to the anchor within allows styling the link without needing 'display:inline-block', which causes issues with older versions of IE

Also, 'href' [is an attribute for anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) `<a>`, not list items `<li>`. If you click a `<li>`; with a href attribute, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the list inline. The following should work:

```
.navtabs li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `li` are by default set to `display: block;` 
This style makes the width as wide as its parent element.

To fix this, give all the `li` tags the style `display: inline-block`.
Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnB8S/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.navtabs li
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
   padding-left:5px;
}
```

Float:left this floats the li element to the left 
display:inline-block; [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873/3030434) to know about Display properties

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx2aC/5/)

**Output:**

[image]