# Why I can't display header and navigation links in one line?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<header style="display: inline"><h1><a href="index.html">:::Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>

<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontakt informacije">Kontakt Informacije</a></li>
    <li><a href="galerija.html" title="Galerija slika">Galerija slika</a></li>
    <li id="empty"><a href="onama.html" title="O nama">O nama</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Although `<header style="display: inline">`, the `<h1>` element is not aligned with the `<ul>` element, but rather `<ul>` element is placed beneath `<h1>`. Tried `<header style="display: inline-block">`, but to no avail. Shouldn't `display: inline` property align items in line?

Comment: Did you  mean `</header>` or  `</h1>`? you seem to have no closing for `<h1>` and two closings for `<header>`

Comment: First thing, is that your HTML is not well formed. You have 2 closing header tagas one in the same line where you open your header and other one between nav and header closing. What is the correct one?

Comment: You can just float the elements like so: http://jsfiddle.net/EJ7K4/1/

Comment: Or you could always stick with inline-blocks for the inner elements like so: http://jsfiddle.net/EJ7K4/3/

Comment: Is there preferable way? I want to make tabbed navigation with those navigation links by using css. Which method, floating or inline-block applied to all elements, would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nav, h, and header are all block elements.
You would have to add the `display: inline;` to all the elements that are predefined block-elements.
This code here does the job:

```
header, nav, ul, li, h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

You can find it applied in the below demo.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D8V66/)

Comment: Since the `nav` is in the `header`, you don't even have to change the display of the header, just the contents. Alternatively, you can float the `h1` to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display: inline-block` on both your `header` and `nav`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <header style="display: inline-block"><h1><a href="index.html">:::Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1></header>

    <nav style="display: inline-block">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontakt informacije">Kontakt Informacije</a></li>
        <li><a href="galerija.html" title="Galerija slika">Galerija slika</a></li>
        <li id="empty"><a href="onama.html" title="O nama">O nama</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, remove the extraneous `</header>` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As your h1 and nav tags are inside header you could use the below css:

```
h1, nav, li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

also, refer to [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)! for knowing why you are using the above.

And refer [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)! to know about block-level elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <header ><h1 style="display: inline;float:left;"><a href="index.html">:::Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h1>

    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li style="display:inline;float:left;margin-top:35px;margin-left:20px;"><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontakt informacije">Kontakt Informacije</a></li>
        <li style="display:inline;float:left;margin-top:35px;margin-left:20px;"><a href="galerija.html" title="Galerija slika">Galerija slika</a></li>
        <li  style="display:inline;float:left;margin-top:35px;margin-left:20px;" id="empty"><a href="onama.html" title="O nama">O nama</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)