# CSS: Inline Parent , Absolute Child - Unexpected Behavior

Tags: html, css, inline, absolute

Sorry if this question has been answered already, I've searched and was unable to find an answer.

I'm having an issue keeping an absolutely positioned element inside of it's parent element.

For example, the following works without the parent having a `display: inline;`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bottom">...</div>
  <div class="top">...</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

and

```
.container {
  position: relative; 
}
.bottom {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 998;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Obviously, the container elements will be displayed on top of each other vertically whereas the intent is to have them side by side. Adding `display:inline;` to the `#container` element "fixes" this by displaying the container elements side by side.

However, when `display:inline;` is added to the parent, it causes the `.top` element that has `position:absolute;` to lose it's alignment and to appear below the intended location. I feel that I'm doing something wrong that is fairly simple, but I'm stumped. Any help or direction is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Try to use [`inline-block`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block) instead of `inline`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I feel silly, I know I tried `inline-block` but must have had an error elsewhere. Whatever the case, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question, because it may helpful to someone who has the exact problem.

You will have to use `display:inline-block;` css attribute to the `.container` div.

> Elements with `display:inline-block` elements are like `display:inline` elements, but they can have a width and height.
>
> Extracted from  [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp): **`inline-block` displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box**