# Images in div do not adjust size based on div percentage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create three menu items evenly spaced out with some text beneath an image. Right now im just trying to get the images to accept a percentage height or width based on class name menuItem but it doesn't seem to work at all. Why is this?

html:

```
    <div id='menu'>
            <div class='menuItem'>
                <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/l/u/5/P/D/A/arrow-50x50-md.png' >
            </div>
            <div class='menuItem'>
                <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/l/u/5/P/D/A/arrow-50x50-md.png'>
            </div>
            <div class='menuItem'>
                <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/l/u/5/P/D/A/arrow-50x50-md.png'>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%:
}

.menuItem {
    display:inline;
    width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `.menuItem` to `display: inline-block` instead because `inline` elements dont respect width and height. And set `max-width: 100%` on the images so that they are restricted by  their parents size

```
#menu {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%:
}

.menuItem {
   display:inline-block;
   width:25%;
}

img{
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mjgk8t3/)

Here is an explanation on the different `display` types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873/3113558

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you explain or point to me to where I could find why inline block worked instead of inline?

Comment: @user2093601 yeah so i explained it briefly but ill include a link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You just gave the images a max-width, not a width. Try this ([Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mjgk8t3/1/))

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%:
}

.menuItem {
    display:inline;
    width:25%;
}

#menu .menuItem img{
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to put the class on the **img** tag itself, not the surrounding div, unless you are using bootstrap which it doesn't look like you are. Bootstrap would provide a few more dependencies than you have working here.