# What is the HTML buttons' default display mode?

Tags: html, css

Each element in HTML has a default display mode like "block", "inline", etc. For example, the "div" display is "block", and the "span" display is "inline".

I need a display mode like the "button" elements.
It's more like the "inline" because you can put some of them in one line, but unlike the "inline" they can have width property.

OK, enough, let's back to my question.
Which display mode do HTML buttons have?

Comment: Look at the available [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop) property-values, and it'll show you the type that you want, though it's not necessarily the same, by default, in every browser.

Comment: Sounds like you want inline-block;

Comment: The `<button>` element is an `inline` element.

Comment: @TylerH: no, it's an `inline-block`, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Comment: @LinkinTED In that case, MDN is wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @LinkinTED you linked to a stylesheet not a definition of element type for a button.

Comment: Yes, it is. To check what's right I made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u7yLmdh/1/). According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block an inline-block can have width/height and an inline element can't...

Comment: @hungerstar, check my testcase in my last comment... it's an `inline-block`....

Comment: Yes, thank you, it's inline-block

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A button is by default an `inline-block`, so multiple buttons without a line break or some will be displayed next to each other:

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
```

If you want them to be under each other, you could display them as `block`:

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

And by changing button's display value to block, you could easily center it like so:
(suppose it has a class of btn)

```
.btn{
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
```