# How to horizontally inline buttons inside a div?

Tags: javascript, css

The code I have now is the following:

```html
<div id="bint">
  <button id="ButtonA">
    Option A
  </button> 
  <button id="ButtonB">
    Option B
  </button>
</div>
```

This code won't align the buttons unless I remove the div tag.
What is the easiest way to put them in line?

Comment: Insert please the full example of code snippet. Because for now it works fine for me, buttons are in one line.

Comment: For me they are appearing inline

Comment: perhaps you mean vertically?

Answer (score 1):

By default the buttons are align in inline-block, so they will appear horizontally.
If you want to present them vertically you sould set a css rule to diplay: block.
You can see more information in the follow link:
[Which display mode do HTML buttons have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434876/which-display-mode-do-html-buttons-have)

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), take a look at this [Flexbox generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) to help you understand it better.