# How to prevent span tags overlapping each other?

Tags: html, css

Why are the `<span>` tags overlapping each other, and how to prevent that?  I need them to wrap around the screen nicely so they don't obstruct the views of the others.

HTML:

```
<span class="alphas">#</span>
<span class="alphas">A</span>
<span class="alphas">B</span>
<span class="alphas">C</span>
<span class="alphas">D</span>
etc...
```

CSS:

```
.alphas {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 12px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #006677;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

See the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/uyg0zdLf/

Comment: `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<span>` tag is inline level by default, `width` and `height` values will not apply. You could set it as inline block, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block) to learn more of the differences between them.

<kbd>**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uyg0zdLf/3/)**</kbd>

```
.alphas {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

One more thing - browser also renders white space on inline* level elements, follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

`span` elements are inline by default. In order to make them generate boxes, you must use `inline-block`:

```css
.alphas {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.alphas {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 12px solid #8AC007;
  padding: 20px; 
  background-color: #006677;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span  class="alphas">#</span>
<span  class="alphas">A</span>
<span  class="alphas">B</span>
<span  class="alphas">C</span>
<span  class="alphas">D</span>
<span  class="alphas">E</span>
<span  class="alphas">F</span>
<span  class="alphas">G</span>
<span  class="alphas">H</span>
<span  class="alphas">I</span>
<span  class="alphas">J</span>
<span  class="alphas">K</span>
<span  class="alphas">L</span>
<span  class="alphas">M</span>
<span  class="alphas">N</span>
<span  class="alphas">O</span>
<span  class="alphas">P</span>
<span  class="alphas">Q</span>
<span  class="alphas">R</span>
<span  class="alphas">S</span>
<span  class="alphas">T</span>
<span  class="alphas">U</span>
<span  class="alphas">V</span>
<span  class="alphas">W</span>
<span  class="alphas">X</span>
<span  class="alphas">Y</span>
<span  class="alphas">Z</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`span` tags are defaulted to an inline display property. You sound like what you want is more along the lines of inline-block. Set it like this:

`.alphas { display: inline-block; }`

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/uyg0zdLf/1/