# HTML background not taking up entire screen space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate this simple portion of a website using html just for practice:
[image]

Here is my html code for it so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.green{
   color:lightgreen;
}

ul{
   background-color:lightgray;
   display:inline;
   padding:10px;
}

li{
   background-color:lightblue;
   color:light-gray;
   display:inline;
   margin:20px;
}

a:hover{
   color:orange;
}

a{
   text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h3 class="green">Display Inline-Block Demo</h3>
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Result</a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

The main problem I am having is that when I run my html code in the w3school html text editor (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default), the gray background under the "HTML", "CSS", and "RESUlT" text is only taking up a portion of the screen space instead of going all the way to the edge of the screen. This is the output I am getting with my code above (also the right side of the picture below is all white space):
[image]

Is there any way I can make that gray background span out to the entire screen? Thank you so much for the help in advance!

Comment: Actually I just realized I can add a padding value to my ul CSS class selector and just say padding:300px; Is this a correct approach? Because it will still look different on various screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can remove `display:inline` for `ul` tag.

```
ul{
   background-color:lightgray;
   padding:10px;
}
```

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/kw8kv7vr/

Comment: @ClayHorder yes it is. Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: OK! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Change the displays of the ul and li to make the grey ul span the whole width:

```
ul{
   background-color:lightgray;
   display:block;
   padding:10px;
}

li{
   background-color:lightblue;
   color:light-gray;
   display:inline-block;
   margin:20px;
}
```

Also, there's a good discussion here on block vs inline vs inline-block: [CSS display: inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for that suggestion! I don't know why that didn't pop up in my head before. I just added a line in the ul that said display:block; That is what you meant correct?

Comment: Yep.  Replace the two display lines in the css with the above.  Have a read of that link to get a better understanding of the differences between blocks, inline and inline-blocks.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .green {
      color: lightgreen;
    }
    ul {
      background-color: lightgray;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    li {
      background-color: lightblue;
      color: light-gray;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: orange;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h3 class="green">Display Inline-Block Demo</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Result</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```