# JQuery auto center on window resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, adaptive-design

Googled around and found a jQuery script for auto centering a div, horizontally and vertically.

Added exact the same as the example gives but by one reason the div is not centered by page load, only on window resize.

Example link code:
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html

Example demo:
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/3.html

The link I made is online (test):
http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/test/index.html

And as you can notice by source-center.js, it is just the same as the examples code is given but it only centers when window is resized.. Thanks

Comment: do you need to use jquery or are you just experimenting? I'd suggest using css

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I can use css, but found this piece of code, witch works online and not with me, and therefor asking if someone knows..

Comment: ok, just checking. Experiment on then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are taking the width of a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) - by definition it takes up the full width of its parent. So, the item is already centered, but your text is left aligned inside it. You need to declare your `div` as an `inline-block` element, then the horizontal centering will work.

A good explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873/844726

Here is the code - I only added the `style` attribute to your `div` (purely for example):

The HTML:

```
<div class="className" style="display: inline-block">
    <p>Centered In The Middle Of The Page With jQuery</p>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(window).resize(function(){

  $('.className').css({
   position:'absolute',
   left: ($(window).width() 
     - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
   top: ($(window).height() 
     - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
  });

 });

 // To initially run the function:
 $(window).resize();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yukg0nv5/

Answer (score 0):

Auto centering a div in a div is quit easy, Here is a code you cloud try!

```
.parent {
position: relative;
}
.child {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Demo:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the method but founded the code above witch should work without setting de with or the height. I used the same code and with my page it won't work correctly and online it does. But I appreciate your suggestion tho!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the inline-block answer you can use position:absolute 
just add

```
.className{
position:absolute; 
}
```

to your css file.

https://jsfiddle.net/26y9aue4/2/

Comment: Which effectively takes the `div` down to an inline element. The solution works, but it doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind when submitting future answers.