# 'Div' and 'Input' tag acting differently

Tags: html, css

I am making a search tool, and the search bar was originally a div, and everything was fine, but when I change it to input tags, the margin on the left disappears. Can someone please explain why this might be happening.

Here's my code (with header HTML removed for security reasons): http://jsfiddle.net/k3pv5cmh/

I have tried `margin: auto`, `margin: 0 auto`, and `margin-left: auto` with `margin-right: auto`. But none of these fix the problem.

On the JS Fiddle you can change the input tags to div tags and see the difference.

Comment: can you please explain bit more what is your requirement?

Comment: a css style that i can add to my style sheet (see js fiddle) to centralize the input box @GirdharSinghRathore

Comment: add css as  margin-left: 100px; or according to your page you can increase and decrease margin-left of input box

Answer (score 1):

An `input` element is an inline element by default. A `div` is a block level element. So change your css to this:

```
#search-bar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 800px;

    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 20%;
    display:block;
}
```

Note: `display:block;`

Comment: You just beat me to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: block;` to your `#search-bar` definition. Input is basically line element, that means `margin: auto;` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs by default have style: `display: inline-block;`

Divs on the other hand, by default have style: `display: block`

The difference is in how much of container does each style takes.
You can see their differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

If you want the same behaviour, you just have to put
`style="display: block"` in your input element and override its default style.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `#container { text-align: center; }` if you want to keep input tag inline. In this case you can get rid of left and right margins of input tag and put something next to it (may be button).