# How to create a div box with dynamic width based on text content?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple `div` that shrinks and expands according to the content contained.

https://jsfiddle.net/qa5dr0x8/

```
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 15px; width:auto;">
    test text
  </div>
</body>
```

Result: the red box expands to the full width of the page. Why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 15px; min-width:100px; display: inline-block">
  test text
</div>
```

[Here's an explanation on `display: inline` & `display: inline-block` - a good read to learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

Comment: `display: inline-block` was the key. thanks.