# React Link component spans the entire width of the div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react Link component that contains a custom Button component that I made.  The Link component's width automatically set to fit it's parent div making areas clickable that shouldn't be.  I messed with the code and had the idea to put the Link into a Span resulting in this code.

```
<span><Link to="/"><Button buttonStyle="primary">Create Account</Button></Link></span>
```

This worked perfectly but I only *sort of* understand why.  Can someone explain this in full?  Why did this fix the clickable area for the Link and button components?

Comment: Set the link to: `display: inline-block` - more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766562/how-to-create-a-div-box-with-dynamic-width-based-on-text-content/34766629#34766629

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Link` renders a `<a>` tag which by default doesnt contain the content inside of it. SO when you are placing a button, I believe the button is styled as `display: block`. So the button is displayed as blocked element relative to the parent of the `<a>` tag. Set the style of the `link` to `display: inline-block`. In that case, the  tag will contain the button and also will be in inline block element relative to its **parent**.

```
<Link to="/" style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
    <Button buttonStyle="primary">Create Account</Button>
  </Link>
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted in other answers, react-router's `Link` component wraps all child elements, and the default styling causes it to fill the full width available to it from the parent, essentially `width: 100%`.

A couple solutions:

1. **`useNavigate`**

   react-router has a hook called [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate) that you could use instead of the `Link` component.

   ```
   import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

   const ButtonLink = () => {
     const navigate = useNavigate();
     return (
       <Button onClick={() => navigate('/')}>
         Text
       </Button>
     );
   };
   ```
2. **`display: contents`**

   Another method of constraining the `Link` component not mentioned in other answers is to style the `Link` component with `display: contents`.

   ```
   <Link to='/' style={{display: 'contents'}}>
     <Button>Text</Button>
   </Link>
   ```

   Using [display: contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box) removes the display box for the parent, replacing it with its children's boxes.

   *Note: Current browser behavior removes this element from the [accessibility tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Accessibility_tree). If you use this property value you should do so with caution, and ensure that (1) you are replacing it completely with an appropriate child, as in the example above, (2) that the child component exists in the accessibility tree, and (3) that it is reachable by screen reading, tabbing and other accessible navigation methods. [More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_contents).*

Answer (score 2):

`Link` component from react router wraps everything that you pass as `children`,in your example `Button` component, with `<a></a>` element. That element is by default `display:block` meaning it will take full width of the parent that holds `Link` component.

So you need to either constrain parent component to desired width or pass class or style to `Link` component and style it in that way:

```html
<span>
  <Link to="/" style={{width: '100px'}}>
    <Button buttonStyle="primary">Create Account</Button>
  </Link>
</span>
```