# Is it possible to set a max width of a label in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want that a label in HTML has a max width of like 100px and if this label has a text that is longer than 100px it gets cut off. A perfect result would be a cut and some points ".." at the end.

I have:

```
<label> This is some long text on my website </label>
```

Desired result would be something like:

***This is some lo..***

Is this possible with CSS alone? For a start it would be okay if it only gets cut at the end. Thank you in advance!

I tried to set the width to 100px in CSS but that only changes the size of e.g. the backgroundcolor of the label and not the text.

Comment: label { width: 100px; }

Comment: The dots is optional. At first i just want the cutoff

Comment: As `label` is an **inline** element, put `display: inline-block` so the `width` works - [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block). To "cutoff", use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @Vucko the overflow:hidden did the trick. Thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```css
label {
  width : 130px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<label> This is some long text on my website </label>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was missing overflow:hidden;