# Issue with divs not appearing side by side

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the child `div`s not appearing side by side. There are two `div`s which appear at the bottom of the first `div`.

I have tried `display:inline-block` - but to no avail.

[image: issue]

```css
div.bodyClass {
  background-color: D4BD6A;
  height: 850px;
}
div.navClassItems {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px:
}
div.secClass1 {
  background-color: F9E18D;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.secClass2 {
  background-color: F9E18D;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbodyWithNav" class="bodyClass">

  <div class="navClassItems">
    <hr>Main Page
    <br>
    <hr>Metrics
    <br>
    <hr>Contact us
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>


  <div class="secClass1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <div class="secClass2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with divs not being contained in parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048168/issue-with-divs-not-being-contained-in-parent-div)

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply `display:inline-block` and set a `(max)-width` to all the children

```css
.bodyClass {
  background-color: #D4BD6A;
  height: 850px;
  font-size:0 /* inline-block gap fix */
}
.bodyClass > div{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  max-width: 250px;
  font-size:16px /* reset font-size */
}
[class*="sec"] {
  background-color: #F9E18D;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbodyWithNav" class="bodyClass">
  <div class="navClassItems">
    <hr>Main Page
    <br>
    <hr>Metrics
    <br>
    <hr>Contact us
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="secClass1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="secClass2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
div.secClass1
{
  background-color:F9E18D;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

div.secClass2
{
  background-color:F9E18D;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

and put an `<hr />` just before the `secClass1` div so that it separates it from the menu above.

Answer (score 0):

Use "`Float:left`" and set their width both to `50%` (Or width of container divided by 2):

```
//below is container class
container{
width: 100%;
}
div.secClass1
{
float: left;
width: 50%;
background-color:F9E18D;
display:inline-block;
}

div.secClass2
{
float: left;
width: 50%;
background-color:F9E18D;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set width to `calc(50% - 125px)` and float them left. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/39/

```
div.secClass1
{
width: calc(50% - 125px);
float: left;
background-color:#F9E18D;
}

div.secClass2
{
width: calc(50% - 125px);
float: left;
background-color:#F9E18D;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using "float: left;" instead

Comment: add a width property and float them left