# How to modify HTML inside PHP by CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I wrote this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> page 1</title>
<body>
<style>

a{
    margin-left:10px;
}
</style>

<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
    $q = " SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = 201102820" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con , $q ) ;
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if ($row["major"]=="computer engineerig"){
               echo "welcome ". $row["name"];
               echo '<a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a>';
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I run it show me like this

```
Welcome stephen ICON
```

the icon(picture) that I put comes in front of the text .

Can I do like this

```
welcome stephen  
ICON
```

I want the icon (picture) comes under the text.

Comment: *Ummm.....* think about it for a minute ;-) *"Storyboard it"*.

Comment: if you separate your HTML and PHP then you can think how this work. just try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML have a tag called Break :) you should echo this :

```
echo "welcome ". $row["name"];
echo "<br />";
echo '<a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a line break

```
echo "welcome ". $row["name"] . '<br/>';
echo '<a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a>';
```

or

```
echo '</p>' . "welcome ". $row["name"] . '</p>';
echo '<a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` and `<img>` are inline elements by default. See this article : [CSS display: inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

So you have to put the ICON block in a block element to see a separation between the name and the icon.

Like this for example :

```
    if ($row["major"]=="computer engineerig")
    {
      echo "welcome ". $row["name"];
      echo '<p><a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a></p>';
    }
```

Or adding a `<br/>` like suggested @Noor Adnan

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        //here you can add php 
?>
<p>welcome <?php echo $row["name"]; ?> </p>
<br />
<a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a>
<?php 
          // here you can add your php
?>
```

If you Separate your HTML and PHP then you can easily add css and HTML inside your PHP.