# I can't seem to be aligning these images properly

Tags: html, css, image, header

This is really some basic html problem, I want to create a small website but I wanted to have my header in the middle of 2 images, my problem basically goes that I cannot get both images to align properly.

[The result I want is in blue letters and the result I have has black letters](http://imgur.com/a/YmkfQ), I'm sure this was kinda unneeded but I decided to include it anyway.

I'm sure, considering I'm a newbie at html/css that I'm doing something wrong over here but basically this is what I have:

HTML FILE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Conversor de Coordenadas</title>
        <script src="conversor.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="conversor.css">
    </head>

    <body><center>

           <br>
                <div class="box"> <img id="globe1" src="globe.gif"/> <h1> Conversor de Coordenadas </h1> <img id="globe2" src="globe.gif"/></div>

                <br>    
                    <div id="background" style="background-image: url(worldmap.gif); height: 400px; width: 520px; "></div>              
                    <p><input type="button">
                    <br>
     </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS FILE:

```
#globe1 {
   float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#globe2 {
   float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
   margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
}


.box {

    width:  1000px;
}
```

Before anything, I tried to do my research but most of the stuff I found wouldn't fix my problem, I've been using w3schools and I've searched a couple of questions here to learn what I know but I seem to have hit a stump cuz I just can't seem to fix this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set your h1 and images to `display: inline-block;`

[image]

From [CSS display: inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

If you add this CSS rule they will line up

```
.box h1 {
  float: left;
  width:  760px;
  text-align: center
}
```

Sample

```css
#globe1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#globe2 {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
}
.box {
  width:  1000px;
}
.box h1 {
  float: left;
  width:  760px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class="box">
  <img id="globe1" src="globe.gif"/>
  <h1> Conversor de Coordenadas </h1>
  <img id="globe2" src="globe.gif"/>
</div>

<br>    
<div id="background" style="background-image: url(worldmap.gif); height: 400px; width: 520px; ">
</div>              
<p>
  <input type="button">
  <br>
```

---

Or you can do this, where you change the markup some and add a CSS rule

HTML

```
  <img id="globe1" src="globe.gif"/>
  <img id="globe2" src="globe.gif"/>
  <h1> Conversor de Coordenadas </h1>
```

CSS

```
.box h1 {
  margin: 0 120px;
  text-align: center
}
```

Sample 2

```css
#globe1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#globe2 {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
}
.box {
  width:  1000px;
}
.box h1 {
  margin: 0 120px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class="box">
  <img id="globe1" src="globe.gif"/>
  <img id="globe2" src="globe.gif"/>
  <h1> Conversor de Coordenadas </h1>
</div>

<br>    
<div id="background" style="background-image: url(worldmap.gif); height: 400px; width: 520px; ">
</div>              
<p>
  <input type="button">
  <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the two image ont afther the other :

```
<div class="box"> <img id="globe1" src="globe.gif"/> <img id="globe2" src="globe.gif"/> <h1> Conversor de Coordenadas </h1> </div>
```

I'm not sure that will work but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I would try wrapping all elements in their own div tag.

```
 <div class="box">
  <div id="globe1">
    <img src="globe.gif"/> 
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>title</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="globe2">
    <img src="globe.gif"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#globe1 {
   float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
}

#globe2 {
   float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
   margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
}

.title {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.box {

}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4thkxhwm/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the CSS3 FlexBox module, see code and fiddle below:

**HTML:**

```
<section class="container">
  <img src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" />
  <h1> Conversor de Coordenadas </h1>
  <img src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" />
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  border:solid;
}

h1{
  border:solid;
  padding-top:10px;
}

img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smlrolland/8x4nyh1o/