# Why isn't display: inline placing my divs side by side properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a simple page with two divs inside a large div which I'm using as a container for the whole page. For being able to do this I'm using the `display: inline` for the divs, but when I do this everything just wrecks itself.

```css
div {
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#container {
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 620px;
}
#options, #forms {
    display: inline;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>BANCO DE LA NACION</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="options">
            <h3>Eliga su operación:</h3>
            <input type="button" name="crear" id="creacion" value="Crear nueva cuenta">
            <input type="button" name="mostrar" id="mostrador" value="Mostrar datos">
        </div>
        <div id="forms">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm wondering if there is another way of making divs spawn right to each other (without the usage of bootstrap which for the moment I'm trying to avoid) or in the case the way I'm doing it is the correct one, which is my mistake?

Comment: Why are you using `display:inline` for div? div are `block` elements.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey well, i'm in the process of learning css and javascript right now. So should I use ´display: inline-block´ when refering to divs?

Comment: Instead of using `display: inline-block` use `float:left`... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inline-block instead of inline.
Read difference between them in:

[What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

[CSS display: inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually helped a lot.

Comment: I had a new issue but it was a sintax error! Sorry for that, you answer was indeed correct

Comment: @Yacomini dear friend please:
1 ) set a id for main div and style it by id.
2 ) create a new queastion for any new question.
Tanks.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this, thanks for all the tips. I primary use div when styiling because almost everytime I use those values in every div generally and if I need to change them I specify by changing the values in the different div, is that not the recommended way to go?

Comment: @Yacomini I can not explain very good because my English is not good. if you "almost everytime I use those values in every div generally" that is good but in a real design you have many div and i think this styles can not be general.

Answer (score 1):

Change inline to inline-block.

Comment: * An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it tolerates HTML elements next to it.
* A block element has some whitespace above and below it and does not tolerate any HTML elements next to it.
* An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.