# Html: Set font-size equal to input height

Tags: html, input, height, font-size

I need to fit `font-size` to `input` height. `Input` looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputt" name="test" value="ddpp" style="height:100px; width:200px; font-size:100px; line-height:100px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'">
```

As you can see the `height`, `font-size` and `line-height` properties are equal to `100px`.  When I `alert()` these properties by `jquery` after page loading all `values` are equal to `100px`. But text inside `input` is not fitting an `input height`. 
I also tried to do this with a `span`:

```
<span id="spann1" style="height:100px;font-size: 100px;border: 1px solid red;font-family: 'Times New Roman'">ddpp</span>
```

As a result the `height` of `span` has changed to 113px and `line-height` became `142px`. Why? Does it mean that `font-size: 100px` is not a `100px` in reality. Then how it works?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can change display property . 
The display property specifies if/how an element is displayed.
Every HTML element has a default display value depending on what type of element it is. The default display value for most elements is block or inline.

[css_display_visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

span has default inline value , you can change display to inline-block .

Inline elements:

```
respect left & right margins and padding, but not top & bottom
cannot have a width and height set
allow other elements to sit to their left and right.
```

Inline-block elements:

```
allow other elements to sit to their left and right
respect top & bottom margins and padding
respect height and width
```

[CSS display: inline vs inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

good luck

Comment: I tried to set `display:inline` for `input`. But nothing changed.

Comment: set display:inline-block instead of inline

Comment: Not working. But anyway `input` has an `inline-block` by default.

Comment: font-size depend on font-family . change font-family and check it .
you can also change padding for vertical align text