# Css Navigation Menu Text

Tags: html, css

I'm new to Stackoverflow, Just want to build simple CSS navigation menu. How can I align these items from left to right and can make sub-items on mouse focus?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test App</title>
    <style>
    li{
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul{
        background-color: green;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            George
        </li>

        <li>
            Belly
        </li>

        <li>
            Mac
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your question is a little vague as "professional" could mean a lot of things to a lot of people.

Comment: Means with proper space, looks so on mouse focus I can change background color of item also or can add sub item also.

Comment: What have you tried before asking this question? have you perhaps looked up some tutorials on how to make a menu before coming here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :) hope this will be helped to you**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">George</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Belly</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Mac</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h4>Dropdown Menu inside a Mac</h4>
<p>Hover over (mouse focus) the "Mac" you can see the dropdown menu.</p>
<p>Hope this will be helped to you,please put a comment if answer is helpful.Good Luck!!!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are very basic ideas behind CSS, so I will not explain them. Hopefully this starts you off.

```css
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  height:55px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:15px;
  padding:20px 10px;
}
.nav li:hover{
  background-color:darkgreen;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test App</title>
  <style>
    li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    ul {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      George
    </li>

    <li>
      Belly
    </li>

    <li>
      Mac
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by changing the `display` css property of `li` element.

```
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

Generally, the `display` property can have [many](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) values - out of which there are mainly 3 values you need to be considered here (*and hereafter*) to make your life beautiful.

1. `display: inline;` : cannot have a width and height set, allows other elements to sit to their left and right.
2. `display: block;` : force a line break after the block element
3. `display: inline-block` : combination of the above properties.

It is fundamental to undestand the basic difference between these values.
You can see a detailed discussion **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)**.