# img inside <li> with property "display: inline" goes out of li tag

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list, `listaAuto`, which is filled with `<li>` items, which contain an `img` for each.

The problem is that if I use the `<li>` property `display: inline;`, they won't expand to contain the images. Instead, if I display them horizontally, they are no mistakes.

I already tried using `overflow: auto`, `height: auto`, `clear: both:` and other solutions, but I still can't find the way.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="listaAuto">
            <li><img src="example.png" width="121.33" height="75.92"/></li>
            <li><img src="example.png" width="121.33" height="75.92"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#listaAuto, li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

li{
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Current output:

[image: Current output]

Comment: Do you mean to use display:inline-block; on the li instead?

Comment: @ovokuro yeah, I solved thanks to the guys below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `inline-block` for the `li` items:

https://jsfiddle.net/y86263mq/

[Based on another Stackoverflow answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873/192729)

Inline elements:

1. respect left & right margins and padding, but **not** top & bottom
2. **cannot** have a width and height set
3. allow other elements to sit to their left and right.
4. see very important side notes on this [here][1].

Block elements:

1. respect all of those
2. force a line break after the block element

Inline-block elements:

1. allow other elements to sit to their left and right
2. respect top & bottom margins and padding
3. respect height and width

**Simple explaination**

`inline-block` elements can have the heights defined. In this case, you're not explicitly setting the heights but the contents are.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:inline-block` for li and remove the unnecessary `clear:both`. 
Refer this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wsmzhn1h/

Answer (score 1):

Adding `float: left;` and removing `clear:both;` on the li should do the trick. https://jsfiddle.net/y8sxhv1z/2/

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
li{
display: inline-block;
}

li img{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#listaAuto, li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

li{
 width: auto;
 float: left;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="listaAuto">
            <li><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=2bb144720a66" width="121.33" height="75.92"/></li>
            <li><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=2bb144720a66" width="121.33" height="75.92"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```