# Why does the progress element occupy the same vertical space even if shrinked in height?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

If you reduce the height of a [progress](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp) element, it becomes visually smaller but it still occupies the same space as if it had original height.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
Bigger progress, div expands as expected
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:30px"></progress>
</div>
<br/>
Normal progress
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33"></progress>
</div>
<br/>
Smaller progress, div doesn't shrink. Why?
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:7px"></progress>
</div>
```

Notice the space above the smaller progress from the above snippet. What causes it to exist? Can it be removed?

I tried shrinking margin, font-size, line-height and such with no success, and I haven't found any info about this behavior.

Comment: You can use vertical-align: top; or float: left;

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Check my answer below, I hope it help you understand the reason this behavior.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Thank you, it does. I cannot give the bounty yet though, must wait 1 day.

Comment: Don't award bounty yet, leave it for 7 days maybe you'll get more better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `progress` is `inline` element, which is inheriting `line-height` from `parent block` to create space above and below of `progress`,

> Such [anonymous inline boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) inherit inheritable properties from their
>   block parent box. Non-inherited properties have their initial value.

Short description to understand the difference between *Inline*, *Inline-block* and *Block* level elements.

> **Inline**: An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it
>   tolerates HTML elements next to it.
>
> **Inline-block**: An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on
>   the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.
>
> **Block**: A block element has some
>   whitespace above and below it and does not tolerate any HTML elements
>   next to it.

In following demo you can see the difference between `inline` and `block` level element.

In the first `div` (`.inline`) the progress bars are inheriting all properties from parent block except `background` and `margin` (these two applies on element itself) and in the second `div` (`.block`) nothing is being inherited.

In other words parent *block* element treats it's child `inline` or `inline-block` level element same as it treats `text` in it.

```css
.inline,
.block {
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.block progress {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
  <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

---

Now there are two better ways to fix this.

First set `font-size: 0;` to parent block element of `inline` element this will remove `line-height`, `white-space` and then reset `font-size` of child inline element with `font-size: initial;` and `font-size: normal;` for IE.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 0;
}

div progress {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
Bigger progress, div expands as expected
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:30px"></progress>
</div>
<br/> Normal progress
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33"></progress>
</div>
<br/> Smaller progress, div doesn't shrink. Why?
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:7px"></progress>
</div>
```

---

The second way is to convert `inline` element to `block` element.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div progress {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:30px"></progress>
</div>
<br/> Normal progress
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33"></progress>
</div>
<br/> Smaller progress, div doesn't shrink. Why?
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:7px"></progress>
</div>
```

Sources:

1. [Inline-boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)
2. [Css-display-inline-vs-inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if you want the progress bar to fill the entire div. But you will have to add the `display:block` style to the progress bar

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div progress{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Bigger progress, div expands as expected
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:30px"></progress>
</div>
<br/>
Normal progress
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33"></progress>
</div>
<br/>
Smaller progress, div shrinks
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:7px"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:block` seems to be the proper solution. But what is the point of `-webkit-apperance` in this scenario? It seems to work even without it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid blue; float:left; width:100%;
}
progress{
  float:left
}
```

```html
Bigger progress, div expands as expected
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:30px"></progress>
</div>
<br/>
Normal progress
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33"></progress>
</div>
<br/>
Smaller progress, div doesn't shrink. Why?
<div>
  <progress max="100" value="33" style="height:7px; vertical-align: top;"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't give it to you, but probably because at that time your solution didn't work. The progress was displayed up or down, but still occupied the same space. I see you got it to work so I'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 0):

div was not behaving as per the content so I tried this. I don't know if this helps you or not.

```
<style>

div{
border: 1px solid blue;
}
progress {
vertical-align: top;
}
#div3{
height: 10px;
}

</style>

<body>
<div>
<progress max="100" value="33" style="height:30px"></progress>  
</div>
<br>

<div>
<progress max="100" value="33"></progress>
</div>
<br/>


<div id="div3">
<progress max="100" value="33" style="height:10px"></progress>
</div>
<br>

</body>
```

Comment: Can anybody explain the reason behind this weird behavior of div element?