# I can't change the dimensions of my DIV which is around an IMG tag

Tags: html, css

Here is part of the code I am working on and I want it to add a background around the whole image when I hover over it but when I set the width and height of the div it won't work and only the bottom part is changed as shown in the snippet.

I would like some help on how to solve this problem.

```css
  #select-background{
 display:inline;
  }
  #select-background:hover{
 display:inline;
 background-color:#c1c1c1;
 height:95px;
 width:95px;
 border-radius:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="select-background"><a href="https://hotmail.com"><img height="75" width="75" src="https://arteminc.github.io/stackoverflow-assets/hotmail.png"/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the display to block or inline-block. That seems to get your current code to highlight the entire image.

```css
  #select-background{
 display:inline-block;
  }
  #select-background:hover{
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:#c1c1c1;
 height:95px;
 width:95px;
 border-radius:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="select-background"><a href="https://hotmail.com"><img height="75" width="75" src="https://arteminc.github.io/stackoverflow-assets/hotmail.png"/></a></div>
```

Comment: I am just curious because I know what block and inline is but what is inline-block?

Comment: The best of both worlds :) This [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block) explains better than I could