# Parent height not covering children's padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is a functional snippet of my code which contains the issue. I am turning radio inputs into pills/buttons.

I am just stumped as to why the container for the radio buttons height is not growing to cover its children's padding?

```css
#contact label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#contact label,
#contact input {
  display: block;
}

#contact input[type=radio].radio-btn {
  display: none;
}
#contact .radio-btn + label {
  display: inline;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#contact .radio-btn:checked + label {
  transition: ease-out .25s;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}

#contact .radio-btn-group {
  margin: auto;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:first-of-type + label {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3rem;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:last-of-type + label {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:not(:first-of-type) + label {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="contact">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <div class="radio-btn-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input id="general" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="general" checked><label for="general">General Enquiry</label><input id="quote" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="quote"><label for="quote">Quote</label><input id="rand" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="rand"><label for="rand">Rand</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the below value from `inline` to `inline-block` :

```
#contact .radio-btn + label {
  /* display: inline; */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Referring to @Oldskool answer on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189810/css-display-inline-vs-inline-block)

> **Inline elements**:
>   respect left & right margins and padding, but not top & bottom
>
> **Inline-block elements**:
>   respect top & bottom margins and padding

```css
#contact label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#contact label,
#contact input {
  display: block;
}

#contact input[type=radio].radio-btn {
  display: none;
}
#contact .radio-btn + label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#contact .radio-btn:checked + label {
  transition: ease-out .25s;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}

#contact .radio-btn-group {
  margin: auto;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:first-of-type + label {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3rem;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:last-of-type + label {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:not(:first-of-type) + label {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="contact">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <div class="radio-btn-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input id="general" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="general" checked><label for="general">General Enquiry</label><input id="quote" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="quote"><label for="quote">Quote</label><input id="rand" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="rand"><label for="rand">Rand</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;` for `#contact .radio-btn + label`

```css
#contact label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#contact label,
#contact input {
  display: block;
}

#contact input[type=radio].radio-btn {
  display: none;
}
#contact .radio-btn + label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#contact .radio-btn:checked + label {
  transition: ease-out .25s;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}

#contact .radio-btn-group {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: gold;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:first-of-type + label {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3rem;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:last-of-type + label {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}
#contact .radio-btn-group input.radio-btn:not(:first-of-type) + label {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form id="contact">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <div class="radio-btn-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input id="general" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="general" checked><label for="general">General Enquiry</label><input id="quote" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="quote"><label for="quote">Quote</label><input id="rand" class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="reason" value="rand"><label for="rand">Rand</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: Awesome that worked a charm, would you mind explaining why this is so?