# Why `<a>` tags set as `display:block` have irregular focus outline shape?

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus

In Google Chrome only - when I have an `<a>` tag set to display block, when it receives focus it has an irregular outline shape. (see screenshot).

[Irregular outline screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJPWl.jpg)

Is this a bug in Chrome or is there some CSS that can cause this issue?

Comment: cannot close as duplicate but here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54665944/8620333

Comment: @chriscalo did you consider the above link? it contain the needed explanation

Answer (score 2):

This issue doesn't occur only for **<a>** elements, it's all focusable elements that behave that way on Chrome. The element area is calculated differently for the actual CSS outline and the focus outline. Not sure the reason why, but the focus handles many functions, for example it can trigger a keyboard, text-to-speech for accessibility, etc. So maybe it needs to be handled differently.

The CSS box for block elements is calculated based on the defined height, width and position. So your element will have the outline defined, and if you have a visible overflow the border and outline don't necessarly match the actual content of the element.

For the focus outline, the text nodes in the element are taken into account in the calculation. The area that is outlined is the combination of the element box plus the text nodes boxes. It's more or less the element box plus the rectangles of the selection range.

In your example, i'm guessing you have a defined height that is less than the height of the text in the element, and so the focus outline has this shape. It takes the area of the text node inside your **<a>** element + the box of the element.

Best way to handle this would be to set the height to auto, or at least make it so that it encloses the text.

See examples of how the focus outline doesn't match CSS outline for block elements with some overflow:

```js
let a = document.getElementById('a');

a.focus()
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 23px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  margin-top: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow-y: visible;
  float: left;
}

#a {
  height: auto;
}

#b {
  height: 40px;
}

#c {
  height: 0px;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id=a tabindex="1">
Click  
<span>to</span>
focus
</div>
<div id=b tabindex="2">
Click  
<span>to</span>
focus
</div>

<div id=c tabindex="3">
Click  
<span>to</span>
focus
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the problem is that the element has `display: block` with a fixed height and also a font-size which is higher than that block. The text is actually higher than the block model, so it overlaps. Below this is illustrated by giving the background a color.

```js
document.getElementById('nc').focus();
```

```css
#nc {
  display: block;
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a id='nc' href='#'>Normal content</a>
```

The chrome browser solves this by 'merging' the outline of both together. Hence the result.

So what to do. That depends on the situation. I can quickly think of 2 solutions, what one to use depends on your context:

**#1 Change the height and padding of the block so the text fits**

```js
document.getElementById('nc_2').focus();
```

```css
#nc_2 {
  display: block;
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<a id='nc_2' href='#'>Normal content</a>
```

**#2 Use `display: inline-block` instead**

```js
document.getElementById('nc_3').focus();
```

```css
#nc_3 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a id='nc_3' href='#'>Normal content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by setting `<a>` with display: inline-block instead of inline, then used margins to adjust.

Occurred when focus set on `<a>` below:

```
<a>
  <img src="...">
  <h1 class="sr-only">Go home!</h1>
</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

it's not bug , it's built in Chrome and some browsers does the same. 
maybe this solve your answer:

```
a:focus,a:active{
    border : 0px!important;
    outline : 0px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I'm not looking to remove the outline as it's very important for accessibility, but I'm just trying to understand why the focus box is an irregular shape.

Comment: Could you please provide HTML ? Tnx

Answer (score -2):

In anchor tag by default outline property is there on focus so we can remove it  with outline:none; on focus.so basically its not browser issue. you can try below css to resolve.

```css
a{
  display:block;
}
a:focus, a:active{
  outline:none !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Remove outline from anchor</a>
```

Comment: A good answer should provide an explanation rather than just a piece of code. Please, try to explain what led you to write this code and how it would help face the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I'm not looking to remove the outline as it's very important for accessibility, but I'm just trying to understand why the focus box is an irregular shape.