# How can i display li elements horizontally

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

Pls how can i display my `li` elements in a horizontal direction, i want the `li` element to contain an image and a text that will display on the image, i tried everything but the `li` element is just displaying vertically

here is my home.page.scss page

```
ul {
    width: 100% !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    margin: auto !important; 
    overflow-x: auto !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
li{
    display: inline !important;
}
.deyDiv{
    position: relative;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-right:2px; 
}
.text{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}
.iuyE{ 
    border-radius:10px;
}
.news{
    width:60%; 
    height:45%;
}
```

here's the  home.page.html page

```
    <ul >
        <li *ngFor="let video of discovrys">
            <div class="deyDiv news">
                <img class="iuyE" [src]="image">
                <h6 class="text">The title of the nese</h6>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Pls what am i doing that's wrong

Comment: Can you create a demo where it reproduces your issue? Right now the code provides a blank output.

Comment: You want the text to be at the bottom of the image ? Or you want the `li` to be displayed horizontally instead of vertically ?

Comment: @Emilien i want the both the horizontal display of the images and the text to display at the bottom of the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace

```css
li {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

with

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Difference b/n them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873). Also try to use `!important` as sparingly as possible.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nidgfm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: it worked, but it made the images to be small, the height and width i gave it didn't work

Comment: Set width and height to img

Comment: Adding a short explanation as to what `display:flex` and `display:inline` does would greatly improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do it using flexbox.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
}

.deyDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to the li list is correct using

```
display: inline;
```

However inside of every `li` item you are using a div element which by default uses

```
display: block;
```

change the display from the class news to either `inline` or `inline-block`,
working code: https://jsfiddle.net/6w5ohxsL/1/