# Why does CSS flex seem to apply padding of inner element twice?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've found a weird quirk with CSS `display: flex` where it seems to be applying the padding of an inner element twice.

I've extracted this snippet from my project. Each paragraph should be 21px high, while their inner spans have some padding that brings their total height to 20.94px, just fitting inside. Without padding the spans would have a height of 17px, so this padding adds 3.94px.

The last paragraph however is set to `display: flex`. The height of the final span is 24.94px, which = 21px + 3.94px. So it's not exactly applying the padding twice, because that would be 20.94 + 3.94. Instead it's applying the padding to the height of the parent paragraph? Which really makes no sense at all! Or maybe instead the `line-height` is being calculated from a different value?

Any ideas what exactly is happening here, and what I can do to return the final paragraph to its proper height?

In case this is a browser quirk/bug more than a CSS quirk, I'm testing this in Chrome 116.

```css
p {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
}

p span {
  padding: 0.132em 0;
}

p:last-child {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>Paragraph 1</span></p>
  <p><span>Paragraph 2</span></p>
  <p><span>Paragraph 3</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Inline Flex Items

### Problem

`<span>`s are inline elements, which means it is assigned `display: inline` by default. Padding only applies to `padding-left` and `padding-right` for inline elements, so in the OP<sup>✤</sup> CSS:

```css
p span {
  padding: 0.132em 0;
}
```

Is actually:

```css
p span {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Moreover if any flex item (ex. `p:last-child span`) is `display: inline`, it will behave as `display: inline-block`. An inline-block element behaves like an inline element but `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` applies to it, hence the last `<p>` is taller than the other two `<p>`s.

### Solution

Since each `<span>` is supposed to have `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`, simply assign `display: inline-block` to each `<span>`:

```css
p span {
  display: inline-block; /* Add this */
  padding: 0.132em 0;
}
```

In the example below, each `<p>` is outlined in blue and each `<span>` is outlined in red. Note the first three `<p>`s the OP CSS is applied and the first two `<p>`s are shorter in height than the third `<p>`. Then in the last three `<p>`s `display: inline-block` is applied to each `<span>` and the height of each `<p>` is equal.

<sup><sup>✤</sup>**O**riginal **P**ost refers to either you or your posted question.</sup>

```css
:root {
  font: 15px/1.4 Georgia;
}

div+div {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}

p span {
  padding: 0.132em 0;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
}

p:last-child {
  display: flex;
}

.solution span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="original">
  <p><span>Paragraph 1</span></p>
  <p><span>Paragraph 2</span></p>
  <p><span>Paragraph 3</span></p>
</div>

<div class="solution">
  <p><span>Paragraph 4</span></p>
  <p><span>Paragraph 5</span></p>
  <p><span>Paragraph 6</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Top/bottom padding does apply to inline elements; if you set a `background-color` on the span you can easily see the difference the padding has. (That's why I have the padding.) That said, I think your explanation that flex mode turns `inline` into `inline-block` is probably the info I needed, so thank you! But rather than increasing the height of all spans like your solution, I think I can probably remove the padding on the final `inline-block` span...

Comment: Yep `p:last-child span {padding: 0}` works too, keeping all rows at the original intended size.

Comment: Simply remove all `padding` properties completely from any `p span` because that's what they are by default.

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68217653/2813224) about padding of inline elements.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of how padding works for inline elements. I have padding set on the spans so that I can consistently set the background colour, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781081/2854284).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I thought you wanted padding for actual height thanks you for clarifying.