# Why does padding not on my <a> tags not cause the containing <div> to expand?

Tags: html, css

I want to preface this by saying that I have solved this issue by adjusting my `<a>` tags to `inline-block`. I am asking why this originally happened with the default `inline` display type.

Consider the below:

```css
.master-container {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

.title-container {
  background-color: #4b6c9e;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.title-container>span {
  color: #fefefe;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.nav-container {
  background-color: slategray;
}

.nav-container>a {
  color: #fefefe;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  /* This fixes the issue */
}

.nav-container>a:hover {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

```html
<div class="master-container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <span>A Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <a href="#">Link One</a>
    <a href="#">Link Two</a>
  </div>
  <div class="body-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have applied padding to the `<a>` tags contained within `nav-container`. However, that padding doesn't appear to affect the containing `div`. When the `a:hover` effect is in play, you can see the newly colored "square" of the `<a>` overlapping the other `div` elements. Why does this happen?

Here are some screenshots of before and after hovering:

[image: Before hover] [image: After hover]

Comment: Add display inline-block to anchor.

Comment: Padding does apply before hover. You just can't see it because there's no background color until hover.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873/7867822) particularly the points about inline elements.

Comment: Inline-block may be what you actually wanted, but it is irrelevant as far as the application of padding is concerned. Give the item a background color and you’ll see it’s there with padding. Your code was fine in relation to padding.